# Let $f(x,y)$ be of class $C^2$. Find a formula for $\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial u\partial v}$ where $x=2u-3v$, $y=u+4v$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Let $f(x,y)$ be of class $C^2$. Find a formula for $\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial u\partial v}$ where $x=2u-3v$, $y=u+4v$

Basically we know that:

$$\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial u\partial v}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial v}(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u})$$

Now,

$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u}=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}*\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial u}+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}*\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial u}=2\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}+1\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$$

So now we must find:

$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial v}(2\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}+1\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y})$$

But I don't know how to further simplify this?

For example, what exactly **is** $2\dfrac{\partial}{\partial v}(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x})$. What is $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$?

Comment: Apply$$\dfrac{\partial }{\partial v}=\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial v}+\dfrac{\partial }{\partial y}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial v}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close. Do the same thing you did with $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u}$ on the function $\dfrac{\partial(\partial f/\partial x)}{\partial v}$.

Comment: Okay let $p=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u}$. Then $\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial v}=\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial x}*\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial v}+\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial y}*\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial v}$, and then replace $p$ by $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u}$?

Comment: Replace $p$ with $\partial f/\partial x$.

Comment: Oh yes $x$, thank you

Comment: You're welcome. :)

Comment: :) I know this is off track, but I see your name is written in Korean (I am learning Korean on my own), does it read jeong jun wan. Is this correct?

Comment: @KSplitX Jeong Jun Hwan. :)